# PHP get date with time from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a little script writen in PHP. It saving text with date (using NOW() function ) to mySQL base. I can show saved content on page with date, but date have a YYYY/MM/DD format. I want to show a time and date on my page. Thank you for help

Comment: Please provide your php script.

Comment: See `date` function.

Comment: You should have a look at [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and its `format()` method.

Comment: Nobody of you actually understood the question, really. He is not asking about PHP's datetime ...  @Machavity

Comment: Nobody of you actually understood the question, really. He is not asking about PHP's datetime ...  @andrewsi

Comment: Nobody of you actually understood the question, really. He is not asking about PHP's datetime ...  @bodi0

Comment: Nobody of you actually understood the question, really. He is not asking about PHP's datetime ...  @karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using NOW() function, it means the date is added to the mysql column on server side, not in PHP. The NOW() function returns date with time together, so if your goal is to store date with time in mysql, your column must be of type `DATETIME`, not DATE.

That way, the value returned by NOW() in mysql will be entirely stored in the column and you'll see there something like "2015-06-06 20:02:14"

Comment: We have a winer! It took only 1 minute. I can`t give you a rep because i am newbie on this site. I am grateful.

Answer (score 3):

assume your date it $mydate:

```
 $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($mydate));
 echo $date;
```

You can edit the first parameter of `date()` to output in whichever format suits you. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I will try your solution when i back to house. I want to add one thing, that my database is holding date with YYYY/MM/DD format. I don't see time here. Is it important? Thank you everyone for replies.

Comment: strtotime() will convert it to a timestamp, and date() will convert that timestamp into the format you specify.